# Print variable in Shell command

Tags: python, shell, arguments, subprocess

I want to extract the text field from a json objcet of a tweet and run it through syntaxnet. I am doing it all in Python.

My code is:

```
import os, sys
import subprocess
import json

def parse(text):
    os.chdir("/var/www/html/alenza/hdfs/user/alenza/sree_account/sree_project/src/core/data_analysis/syntaxnet/models/syntaxnet")
    #synnet_output = subprocess.check_output()
    subprocess.call(["echo 'hello world' | syntaxet/demo.sh"], shell = True)
    #print synnet_output


for line in sys.stdin:
    line1 = json.loads(line)
    text = line1['avl_lexicon_text']
    print text
    synnet_output = parse(text)
```

Now, instead of `echo 'hello world'` in `parse` function, I want to echo `text` there. That is I want to feed the `text` variable to `syntaxnet/demo.sh` file. I tried doing `subprocess.call(["echo text | syntaxet/demo.sh"], shell = True)` but that did not work. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use string formatter `%s` and substitute the text

```
def parse(text):
    os.chdir("/var/www/html/alenza/hdfs/user/alenza/sree_account/sree_project/src/core/data_analysis/syntaxnet/models/syntaxnet")
    #synnet_output = subprocess.check_output()
    subprocess.call(["echo '%s' | syntaxet/demo.sh"%text], shell = True)
    #print synnet_output
```

If you suspect that your text may have single quotes, then you can escape it:

```
text = text.replace("'", "\\'")
```